# Arrow under navigation

Tags: html, css

Hi I've looked up ways to place an arrow under my navigation but I can't get to work on my navigation bar. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<nav>

      <div class="hello"></div>
            <ul>
              <li class="icon-home"><a href="Premiership.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>

            <li class="arrow"> <a  class="star" href="#">England</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Premiership.html">Premiership</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href= "Unavailble.html">Championship</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Unavailble.html">League 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Unavailble.html">League 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">France</a>
                <ul >
                    <li id="r"><a href="Unavailble.html">Ligue 1</a> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">Germany </a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Unavailble.html">Bundesliga</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">Italy</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Unavailble.html">Serie A</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">Spain</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Unavailble.html">La Liga</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>    
            <div class="handle"> Menu </div>
        </nav>
```

I thought that is css would work but it hasn't

```
li a:after {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 6px solid #333;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px
}
```

my code https://jsfiddle.net/jzqv6kr0/

Comment: What are these "ways" you've looked up how to place an arrow. I don't see anything in your code where an arrow would come from. If you are using Bootstrap the `class='arrow'` might produce an arrow icon.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the arrow is there it's just that the `overflow:hidden` on the `ul` means you can't see it.

I've adapted your code a little (see the snippet below) but it requires some tweaks to get it exactly as you might like. I've colored the arrow red for simplicity.

```
nav ul {
    /* overflow:hidden; REMOVE */ 
}

nav ul li.arrow:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 6px solid red;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px
}
```

```css
nav ul {
  background-color: #43a286;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  transition: max-height 0.4s;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 12.3%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #399077;
}
nav ul li.arrow:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 6px solid red;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #399077;
  margin-left: -3%;
  z-index: 150;
}
nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: block;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5%;
  width: 165px;
}
nav ul li a,
visited {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'CFJackStory-Regular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="hello"></div>
  <ul>
    <li class="icon-home"><a href="Premiership.html"><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="arrow"> <a class="star" href="#">England</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="Premiership.html">Premiership</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="Unavailble.html">Championship</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="Unavailble.html">League 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="Unavailble.html">League 2</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">France</a>

      <ul>
        <li id="r"><a href="Unavailble.html">Ligue 1</a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">Germany </a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="Unavailble.html">Bundesliga</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">Italy</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="Unavailble.html">Serie A</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```